# Storage size isn't known error with structures

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to declare structures in my main() that I built in a separate file, but am getting the error:

```
error: storage size of 'phone' isn't known
```

Here is the code for main.c:

```
#include "header.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct firstAndLast name;
    struct contact phone;
    struct address adr;
    struct allInfo individual;

    print_person(individual);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the function.c file that I wrote the structures in:

```
#include "header.h"
struct firstAndLast
{
    char firstName[20];
    char lastName[20];
};
struct contact
{
    int pNumber;
};
struct address
{
    struct firstAndLast person;
    struct contact phoneNumber;

    char streetAddress[100];
    char city[50];
    char province[50];
    char postalCode[10];
};
struct allInfo
{
    struct address addr;
    char occupation[50];
    double salary;
};
void print_person(struct allInfo indiv)
{
    printf("%s \n",indiv.addr.person.firstName);
}
```

And this is the header.h file:

```
#ifndef nS
#define nS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct firstAndLast;
struct contact;
struct address;
struct allInfo;
void print_person(struct allInfo indiv);

#endif
```

I'm not sure why I am getting this error. I put all of the functions in the header file and used #include "header.h" for both my main.c and functions.c files, so it should recognize the structures exist. Is there a problem with the way that I declared the structures in main() or how I listed them in my header? I don't see any typos in my code, so I'm really lost and don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `struct contact
{
    int pNumber;
};` is not seen by `main.c` which has `struct contact phone;` - Its unknown.

Comment: Every C file that uses the structure needs to see the full struct definition. It's not enough for the C file to know that the struct exists. Move your full struct definitions into the header file.

Comment: You can define (and declare) pointers to incomplete types, but you can't declare actual structures like `struct contact phone;` unless the full details of `struct contact` are known.  Since the details are not defined in the header, you can't define the variable in the `main.c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to move full struct definitions into the header file.

```c
#pragma once
#ifndef nS
#define nS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct firstAndLast
{
    char firstName[20];
    char lastName[20];
};
struct contact
{
    int pNumber;
};
struct address
{
    struct firstAndLast person;
    struct contact phoneNumber;

    char streetAddress[100];
    char city[50];
    char province[50];
    char postalCode[10];
};
struct allInfo
{
    struct address addr;
    char occupation[50];
    double salary;
};
void print_person(struct allInfo indiv);

#endif
```

Moreover, please initialize each variable before using them.

For example:

```c
    struct firstAndLast name;
    strcpy(name.firstName, "firstNameA");
    strcpy(name.lastName, "lastNameB");
    struct contact phone;
    phone.pNumber = 01234567;
    struct address adr;
    adr.person = name;
    adr.phoneNumber = phone;
    strcpy(adr.streetAddress, "ABC street");
    strcpy(adr.city, "DEF city");
    strcpy(adr.province, "GH");
    strcpy(adr.postalCode, "12345");
    struct allInfo individual;
    individual.addr = adr;
    strcpy(individual.occupation, "Occupation");
    individual.salary = 1234.56;
    print_person(individual);
```